# making an app for iPhone 4 in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am making an app for iPhone 4 only and  my designer files are having resolution of 640*920 .Now I have confused that what is the frame size I have to take when I am making an app.i.e 320*460 or 640*920

Comment: Please choose a title that describes/summarizes your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 320*460.
The device will automatically scale the image to fit the pixels.

It might be a good idea to provide a graphic for 320px*460px and lets call that `foo.png`
and then include a grapic for 640px*920px and call that `foo@2x.png`. That way if the device is an iPhone 4 or 4s it will automatically use the higher resolution graphic.

Comment: what about the label frames and button frames?

Comment: Stick to coding for a resolution of 320px*460px. The device will automatically translate to the iPhone 4 resolution. Apple have made coding for the new resolution quite easy. We don't even have to think about it.